# Does spring data mongodb support $each operator on $addToSet?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Is there anyway i can do [$each](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) on Update.addToSet() on spring mongodb ?

Currently when i pass the array object as the addToSet param, 
it's only using $addToSet without the $each, resulting in putting the passed array into the existing array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a working version of a custom Update class,
mixed with the solution proposed in https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-471

```
public class MyUpdate extends Update {
    public MyUpdate myAddToSet(String key, Object value, MongoOperations ops) {
        BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
        ops.getConverter().write(value, dbObject);
        this.addToSet(
            key,
            dbObject
        );
        // dont do this, will cause serialization exception
//      System.out.println(this.getUpdateObject().toString());
        return this;
    }
    public MyUpdate myAddToSetAll(String key, Collection<Object> values, MongoOperations ops) {
        BasicDBList eachList = new BasicDBList();
        for (Object value : values) {
            BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
            ops.getConverter().write(value, dbObject);
            eachList.add(dbObject);
        }
        this.addToSet(
            key,
            BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$each", eachList).get()
        );
        // dont do this, will cause serialization exception
//      System.out.println(this.getUpdateObject().toString());
        return this;
    }

    public MyUpdate myPushAll(String key, Object[] values) {
        super.addMultiFieldOperation("$pushAll", key, values);
        return this;
    }
    public MyUpdate myPush(String key, Object[] values) {
        super.addMultiFieldOperation("$push", key, values);
        return this;
    }
    public MyUpdate myPush(String key, Object value) {
        super.addMultiFieldOperation("$push", key, value);
        return this;
    }
}
```